# PHP unlink error

Tags: php, unlink

I've got a problem with deleting the uploaded images.

It inserts in the database and uploads just **fine** but it won't delete.

**Example:** I have two tables, **modelImages** and **Model**. In **Model** I save the path of one main image, but in **modelImage** there can be a lot of them. The tables are linked via **modelID**.

This is an example how the path looks like:**img/1/1/someImageName.png**.

(first 1 - makerID, second 1 - modelID).

```
include('connect.php'); //connect to database
$modelID=$_GET['modelID'];
$makerID=$_GET['makerID'];
$path="img/".$makerID."/".$modelID."/";

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT images FROM modelImages WHERE modelID='$modelID'")) {

    $stmt->execute();    
    $stmt->bind_result($images);

    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        if($images!=$path){
            unlink($images);
        }
    }

    $stmt->close();

}
else {
    printf("Prepared Statement Error: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
}

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT mainImage FROM model WHERE makerID='$makerID' AND modelID='$modelID'")) {    

    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($mainImage);

    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        if($mainImage!=$path){
            unlink($mainImage);
        }
    }

    $stmt->close();

}
else {
    printf("Prepared Statement Error: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
}
```

When I just use the first code , it deletes all the images from the **modelImages** table and if I just use the second code, it deletes the one image from the **model** table.

But if I use them together I get the `unlink()` error:

```
Warning: unlink(img/1/1/image1.png) [function.unlink]: No such file or directory in /home/...
Warning: unlink(img/1/1/image2.png) [function.unlink]: No such file or directory in /home/...
Warning: unlink(img/1/1/image3.png) [function.unlink]: No such file or directory in /home/...
Warning: unlink(img/1/1/image4.png) [function.unlink]: No such file or directory in /home/...
```

**Conclusion**: The **unlink** won't work if I use both of the querys together.

Comment: `echo getcwd();` PS: you're in risk by accepting the direct user input as-is that is passed to `unlink()`

Comment: you're doing prepared statements all wrong.  http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: The first code section already deletes all images in your path. That's why the second `unlink();` throws warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use relative paths unless a) you are absolutely sure, what the current work directory is (see `getcwd()`), or b) it is intended, that the path is located relative to difference work directories (like in workdirectory-aware CLI-tools). Always use, or create absolute paths

```
"/path/to/img/".$makerID."/".$modelID."/";
__DIR__ . "/../path/to/img/".$makerID."/".$modelID."/";
```

I would prefer the second one, because it is more portable.

Comment: Using `echo getcwd();` I got `/home/mainSite/public_html/site` and I changed my path to `$path="/home/mainSite/public_html/site/img/".$proizvodacID."/".$modelID."/";` but it didn't work.